# Vuejs emit not working form child to parent

Tags: javascript, vue.js, parent-child, emit

I'm working on this app and the idea is to show details of the cars in a sidebar on click. There are several issues like the sidebar is showing four times and I resolve it somehow but I don't know why is it showing four times. now I don't getting any response on emit call help me out please, I try $parent.$emit, $root.$emit but not seems working!!!

```js
<template>
  <div class="home">
    <!-- warehouse details  -->
    <div
      v-for="(detail, detailindex) in details"
      :key="detailindex"
      class="container mt-5 mb-5"
    >
      <h1>
        {{ detail.name }}
        <span class="location">{{ detail.cars.location }}</span>
      </h1>
      <!-- vehicle details   -->
      <SingleGarage :detail="detail"> </SingleGarage>
    </div>
      <b-sidebar
      id="my-sidebar"
      title="Sidebar with backdrop"
      backdrop-variant="dark"
      ref="mySidebar"
      backdrop
      shadow
      @emitData="testingEmit()"
    >
      <div class="px-3 py-2">
        <h1>{{currentCar}}</h1>
      </div>
    </b-sidebar>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
// @ is an alias to /src
import axios from "axios";
import SingleGarage from "../components/SingleGarage";
export default {
  components: { SingleGarage },
  name: "Home",
  data: () => ({
    details: String,
    currentCar: 'String',
  }),
  methods:{
    testingEmit(data){
      this.currentCar = data
      console.log('data from emit',data)
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    axios
      .get("https://api.jsonbin.io/b/5ebe673947a2266b1478d892")
      .then((response) => {
        var results;
        response.data.forEach((element) => {
          element.cars.vehicles.sort((a, b) => {
            a = new Date(a.date_added);
            b = new Date(b.date_added);
            results = a > b ? -1 : a < b ? 1 : 0;
            return results * -1;
          });
        });
        this.details = response.data;
      });
  },
};
</script>
```

```js
<template>
  <div class="vGrid mt-4">
    <div
      class="gridItem border vehicle singleCar"
      v-for="(vehicle, vehicleIndex) in detail.cars.vehicles"
      :class="'griditem' + vehicleIndex"
      :key="vehicle._id"
    >
      <SingleCar
        :vehicle="vehicle"
        @click.native="testingTef(vehicleIndex)"
      ></SingleCar>
    </div>


  </div>
</template>
<script>
import SingleCar from "@/components/SingleCar";
export default {
  name: "SingleGarage",
  components: { SingleCar },
  props: ["detail"],
  data: () => ({
    dummyImg: require("@/assets/img/dummycar.png"),
    currentCar : 1
  }),
  methods: {
    testingTef(vehicleIndex) {
      this.$parent.$emit('emitData',this.detail.cars.vehicles[vehicleIndex].make)
      this.$root.$emit('bv::toggle::collapse', 'my-sidebar')
      console.log(this.detail.cars.vehicles[vehicleIndex].make)
      console.log(this.detail.cars.vehicles[vehicleIndex].date_added)
      this.currentCar = this.detail.cars.vehicles[vehicleIndex].make;
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

```js
<template>
  <div class="singleCar">
    <!-- conditionally show image  -->
    <img
      class="carImg"
      :src="vehicle.img"
      v-if="vehicle.img"
      alt="No Preview"
    />
    <img class="carImg" :src="dummyImg" v-else alt="No Preview" />
    <div class="p-3">
      <h3 class="make">{{ vehicle.make }}</h3>
      <div class="modelDetails">
        <div class="model d-flex ">
          <p class="bold">Model:</p>
          <p class="price ml-auto ">{{ vehicle.model }}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="price d-flex ">
          <p class="bold">Price:</p>
          <p class="price ml-auto ">&euro;{{ vehicle.price }}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <p class="dateAdded ml-auto ">{{ vehicle.date_added }}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: "SingleCar",
  props: ["vehicle"],
  data: () => ({
    dummyImg: require("@/assets/img/dummycar.png"),
  }),
  methods:{
      working(){
          console.log('working');
          console.log(this.vehicle.make)
      }
  }
};
</script>
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: try just this.$emit

Comment: I see `@emitData` is this a supported feature?
I could not find it in here https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/sidebar#events

Comment: ohh its actually `@emitData="testingEmit()"`  to `@emit-data="testingEmit"` otherwise the Arguments are not passed. The renaming is because of an autmatic case transformation, [see the docs](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-custom-events.html#event-names)

Comment: sorry, still not working...

Comment: https://github.com/UsamaKhushnood/frank-garage here is the repo link you can check this yourself if comfortable. this effort will be apriciated

Answer (score 1):

So a few things you can try to fix this

in your `Home.vue` you can change

```
@emitData="testingEmit()"
```

to

```
@emitData="testingEmit"
// or
@emitData="testingEmit($event)"
```

You are telling to the function `testingEmit` that is not params to parse. So you need to take out the `()` and Vue will parse everything that comes from the `$event` or you cant say put the `$event` as a param in your `testingEmit` (second option).

For your `SingleGarage.vue` you can take the `$parent.$emit` and replace it with

```
this.$emit('emitData',this.detail.cars.vehicles[vehicleIndex].make)
```